# CSS: Semi-transparent text over semi-transparent :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css

Just saw something for the first time with opacity versus rgba and trying to confirm if/why the two don't mix well as it appears.

Basic example:

I've got a fullscreen div with a background image.  That div has a dark overlay using an :after pseudo with a dark hex background-color and opacity.

I then have an absolutely positioned, light-colored heading on top using z-index and rgba.

When I do it with the mixed hex BG and rgba heading, the heading looks like a solid grey - as if the heading is transparent, but that the dark :after pseudo element loses its transparency where the heading is.

By changing the heading to hex and opacity, rather than rgba, everything's transparent exactly as the design was going for.

Can anyone explain why mixing the two is causing trouble?  I'm having a hard time finding the right Google/Stack search to get a clear answer.

**Abridged version of the HTML**

```
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
    Some content
  </div>
  <h2 class="transparent">The heading in question</h2>
</section>
```

**The abridged CSS:**

```
#banner {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('pathto/image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;  
}

#banner:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.35;
}

#banner .inner {
  z-index: 2;
}

.transparent {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: Threw your code into a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dougstewart/pen/bOXGGp) but I'm not seeing anything irregular. Can you make a pen illustrating the problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried your code and it seems that both the text and the :after are transparent.

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach...

```css
#banner {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Pigeon_Point_Lighthouse_%282016%29.jpg/220px-Pigeon_Point_Lighthouse_%282016%29.jpg');
  background-size: cover;  
}

#banner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
}

#banner .inner {
  z-index: 2;
}

.transparent {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 53px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
    Some content
  </div>
  <h2 class="transparent">The heading in question</h2>
</section>
```